# how to reach files of my project in azure

Tags: macos, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core-mvc

I am really new to azure, I had to create an azure account , because I am using visual studio on mac and it just let me to publish my websites on azure , so I created azure and then it published my project on azure account. everything is fine in azure and my project works fine,

My problem is that I wonder to know how is it possible to download this published project? because I need to transfer the project to the other host in GoDaddy. I really appreciate any help. Please and Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the **Advanced Tools** tap within your App Service and click on the **Go** link. This will open the Kudu environment for your app. Then click on Debug console and select PowerShell. Finally navigate to site and click on the download button next to wwwroot:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your care, but I can not find advanced setting, where is it exactly?

Comment: Click on your app service and find the advanced *tools* link within the DEVELOPMENT TOOLS section.

Comment: when I click on app service it show me a page , the one which I have uploaded. there is no advanced tools or development tools .should I search it on somewhere some other parts?

Comment: click on the app which you marked blue in your screenshot

Comment: the username and password of your azure account will work if you have sufficient rights.

Comment: You can go to the Access Control (IAM) blade within your App Service and check whether your user has e. g. the contributor or owner right. Also, try to use a different browser.

Comment: excuse me for another question, should I download folders on root one by one right? some of them has error on extracting zip files which it has been downloaded

Comment: no, just download the whole wwwroot folder which contains all your web app files

Comment: thank you very much it works fine, but it has Error 500, I should contact with Godaddy i think